# How to change Default Screen Options in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a way to change the default screen options in the post editor.
I want to hide certain options by default.  I am putting together a family recipe site and don't want to overwhelm users with too many options.  I don't want to log in as each user and changing their options manually.  I've combed through WP core files and theme files and can't find very many references to screen-options.  Is it defined somewhere in the database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [default_hidden_meta_boxes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/default_hidden_meta_boxes/) filter

```
add_filter( 'default_hidden_meta_boxes', 'my_hidden_meta_boxes', 10, 2 );
function my_hidden_meta_boxes( $hidden, $screen ) {
    return array( 'tagsdiv-post_tag', 'tagsdiv', 'postimagediv', 'formatdiv', 'pageparentdiv', ''); // get these from the css class
}
```

or

```
add_filter( 'hidden_meta_boxes', 'my_hidden_meta_boxes', 10, 2 );
```

Bonus: To understand how it works have a look at the core function [get_hidden_meta_boxes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_hidden_meta_boxes)(). Here's a simplified version:

```
function get_hidden_meta_boxes( $screen ) {
    $hidden = get_user_option( "metaboxhidden_{$screen->id}" );
    if ( $use_defaults ) {
        $hidden = apply_filters( 'default_hidden_meta_boxes', $hidden, $screen );
    }
    return apply_filters( 'hidden_meta_boxes', $hidden, $screen, $use_defaults );
}
```

Comment: Be advised that this only works on NEW users OR users who haven't already made any customisations to their screen options; perhaps [another way to handle it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/19972/1839) if you run into this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The default screen options are saved in `wp_usermeta` the `meta_key` is `metaboxhidden_post`.

I think the easiest way to set default options (or to hide specific boxes) would be to use a plugin like [adminimize](http://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/). I personally use the [advanced custom fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin for this task (and a lot more).

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. I saw adminimize when searching for plugins for this task and saw that it is for v. 3.6-beta3.  I am running 3.9.1.  That is the only reason I didn't bite. Can I safely install it?

Comment: I guess it is safe to use. It comes from a good and experienced developer. If you check under "compatibility" you usually get a pretty good idea. Where does it say that it is for v3.6-beta3?

Comment: At the link you posted - wordpress.org  "Requires: 2.5 or higher -Compatible up to: 3.6-beta3 - Last Updated: 2013-6-6 - I'll try it though... I guess it can't hurt.  Thanks so much.  The  reason I hesitate to use plugins that haven't been updated is that I fear they won't be compatible with the next major WP upgrade and perhas the developer is moving on to bigger and better things. It must be a  pain to revise the plugins each time WP changes.

Comment: Ah yes sorry. I didn't see that. I would give it a shot... You can still try https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/ though.

Comment: When I installed the adminimize plugin it suggested admin tweaks as well. Turns out that admin tweaks was all I needed. I was able to hide things in the screen options.  It hides for all but that is no biggie.  If i really need something I can change the settings.  That is what the adminimize would help with but no need ... like swatting a fly with a baseball bat.  It is not likely I'll need the hidden  items. I am going to check out  the advanced custom fields plugin though. That looks amazing.  I might have use for that on other sites. Thanks so much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @alpipego Would you mind explaining how Advanced Custom Fields can be used to set default screen options?

Comment: Acf can be used to hide default elements on any wordpress post admin page.

Comment: This helped me out alot! Needed this information to edit `edit_product_per_page` since it was so high, that I was hitting 502 error. - Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A slight modification to Zendka's answer. I just wanted to remove one item from the list, leaving the array otherwise unchanged.

```
add_filter( 'default_hidden_meta_boxes', 'show_author_metabox', 10, 2 );
function show_author_metabox( $hidden, $screen )
{
    $authorkey = array_search( 'authordiv', $hidden );
    unset( $hidden[ $authorkey ] );

    return $hidden;
}
```

In my case I was removing the 'authordiv' from the hidden list, swap that out with whatever metabox you want to remove from the hidden meta boxes.

I don't check for the existence of the metabox before unsetting it, because it doesn't produce any PHP notices/errors if there are no results from the array_search.